# Using AutoMapper with Resharper causes Visual Studio ram and CPU consumption to surge

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, automapper

[image: Resource useage]

All i'm doing is using ForMember mapping in AutoMapper. The system becomes so sluggish it's unuseable. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. Extremely annoying! Did you finda solution to this?

Comment: No we used to abandon AutoMapper and write our own extension methods. Either that or you turn off Resharper when you're working on AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ReSharper → Help → Profile Visual Studio. This will download and attach a profiler, capture a performance snapshot and package it up and send it to JetBrains, where we can investigate what's going on. Any additional detail, such as size of project, size of the automapper related source file, etc. would also be very helpful.

Comment: I am having the same problem and have submitted a profile of VS to the JetBrains team, as requested. I will post a solution when I head back.